# wordpress adding links easily

Tags: wordpress, firefox-addon, bookmarks

we have an author that wants to be able to easily bookmark various articles and have them appear in a wordpress backed site. Over the years we have been using a cobbled together approach where we use the delicious toolbar and it feeds to a google reader. They bookmarked using these tools and we used wordpress to consume the rss feeds they produced. Now google has removed this feature.

Im hesitant to add yet another bookmarking/rss service out there for fear that I will be back to this problem in 6 months. I was thinking of writing or finding a simple firefox addon that would just create a link or blog post based on the url (and possible scan the html or css). It seems like this is a common problem, any other ideas or suggestions on how to solve this? I proposed just having our author use wordpress admin to add links, but that was too cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the "Press This" bookmarklet that comes with WordPress? It's on the Settings → Writing menu. Just drag it up to the bookmark toolbar in your browser.

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was looking for, cant believe I didnt find it in google searching!